# htaccess rewrite: choose rule based on language

Tags: .htaccess, if-statement, url-rewriting

6 hours of reserach and experiments to figure out what i think is simple - and no effect, so I'm must ask:

I have domain www.example.com in htaccess file, there is redirect implemented to non-www version example.com.

What i need to do is redirect it further based on user language, like so:

IF user language is "X" THAN DO NOTHING (keep: example.com)
ELSE (any other language) REWRITE TO example.com/otherlanguage/

Could any of you wonderfully skilled stackoverflow users help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

So i finally found solution:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !^pl.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://imaginakcja.pl/en/ [R=301,L]
```

And you read this like this:

```
RewriteCond = IF
%{this browser header value} 
! = IS NOT 
^pl = language string begining with "pl"
.+ = followed by any other character
[NC] = regarding letter case
RewriteRule = THAN
^$ = whole request (A)
http://example.com (B)
[R=301,L] = switch A to B permamently, finish
```